# Kendo Datepicker - Append Month to Year in Navigation Pane

Tags: angular, kendo-datepicker, kendo-angular-ui

I want to Append month to year (2020) in Kendo Datepicker on left navigation pane. So the final output should be Jan-2020.

This is in Angular project.

[image]

Comment: That's not possible. Check the documentation

Comment: Could you please provide link of that documentation? Not able to find.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/

Comment: This is very much possible and the answer to this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55461619/how-can-i-add-jan-to-the-kendo-datepicker-angular2-pop-up-left-navigation-it

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. I solved problem. I hope it helps you

.ts ====>>

```
  async yearCalc(){
 this.now=moment().year();
  debugger;
   for(var i=2008;i<=this.now+5;i++)
   {
     
        this.year.push(i);
   
   }
}
```

.html====>>

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:300px;" [data]="year.reverse()" [value]="now">
  </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).